# Why does Html.ActionLink render "?Length=4"

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm VERY confused as to why this code

```
Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home", new { hidefocus = "hidefocus" })
```

results in this link:

```
<a hidefocus="hidefocus" href="/Home/About?Length=4">About</a>
```

The `hidefocus` part is what I was aiming to achieve, but where does the `?Length=4` come from?

Comment: This behavior also appears with the Html.BeginForm() methods.

Answer (score 345, accepted):

The Length=4 is coming from an attempt to serialize a string object. Your code is running this `ActionLink` method:

```
public static string ActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
```

This takes a `string` object "Home" for routeValues, which the MVC plumbing searches for public properties turning them into route values. In the case of a `string` object, the only public property is `Length`, and since there will be no routes defined with a Length parameter it appends the property name and value as a query string parameter. You'll probably find if you run this from a page not on `HomeController` it will throw an error about a missing `About` action method. Try using the following:

```
Html.ActionLink("About", "About", new { controller = "Home" }, new { hidefocus = "hidefocus" })
```

Comment: @Blah_Blah these days I don't use this at all, prefer writing my own <a> tags and just using Url.Action("Action", "Controller")

Comment: @roryf no worries ... this was used in a code review as a best practices, they didn't check the date.  There really should be a way to filter the stackoverflow by date ...

Comment: Great answer.

Just to add this also happens on Html.BeginRouteForm for the same reason.

Html.BeginRouteForm("Route", "Action", FormMethod.Post))

Should be

Html.BeginRouteForm("Route", new{ action = "AgentSignUp"}, FormMethod.Post)

that gets rid of the weird length thing

Comment: Also happens with `Url.Action()`. Changing from `Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { area = "" })` to `Url.Action("Action", new { controller = "Controller", area = "" })` keeps the Length property from showing up.

Comment: To avoid those kinds of situation, you can always specify what parameters you are passing, like:
`Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { hidefocus = "hidefocus" })`

Comment: Thanks! :) That was a gotcha, it was looking for routevalues.

Answer (score 200):

The way I solved this is was adding a null to the fourth parameter before the anonymous declaration (`new {}`) so that it uses the following method overload: (linkText, actionName, controllerName, routeValues, htmlAttributes):

```
Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home", null, new { hidefocus = "hidefocus" })
```

Comment: This is the best answer if you're not linking between Areas. If you need to specify the area for the link, you would need to specify the routeValues with the `controller` and the `area` to keep the Length property from showing up in the URL.

Comment: @JohnWasham Actually, you don't need to specify the controller in the `routeValues` but only the area. 

For example: `Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home", new {@area = "Admin"}, new { hidefocus = "hidefocus" })`

Comment: @epiplon, the reason I specify the controller like that is because if you ever don't include htmlAttributes as the last argument of `ActionLink`, MVC will include a weird `Length=x` parameter at the end of the URL. For instance, put this on a page, then view the source of your page, and you'll see what I mean:

`@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home", new { area = "Admin" }, new { hidefocus = "hidefocus" })`
`@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home", new { area = "Admin" })`

But if you put the `controller` entry in the `routeValues`, it will never put `Length=x` in the URL.

Comment: @epiplon, you also don't need to use `@` in `@area = "Admin"`, just so you know.

Answer (score 90):

You forgot to add the HTMLAttributes parm.

This will work without any changes:

```
Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home", new { hidefocus = "hidefocus" },null)
```

Comment: I don't know,why this is not worked for me.i tried with  "new{hidefocus=""}",And this works for me.

Answer (score 29):

The parameters to ActionLink are not correct, it's attempting to use the "Home" value as a route value, instead of the anonymous type.

I believe you just need to add `new { }` or `null` as the last parameter.

EDIT: Just re-read the post and realized you'll likely want to specify null as the second last parameter, not the last.

Comment: BTW They should remove one method as it's not possible to use it!

Answer (score 5):

```
Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home", new { hidefocus = "hidefocus" }, new { })
```

This will take the overload: 
string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, Object routeValues, Object htmlAttributes

Answer (score 3):

Just remove "Home" (name of the controller) so that the code would be:

```
Html.ActionLink("About", "About", new { hidefocus = "hidefocus" })
```

Comment: No, you need to change "Home" for null

Answer (score 3):

Kindly use right overloaded method with five (5) parameters. Example:

```
@using (@Ajax.BeginForm("Register", "Account", null,
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        OnSuccess = "OnSuccess",
        OnFailure = "OnFailure",
        OnBegin = "OnBegin",
        OnComplete = "OnComplete"
    }, new { @class = "form-login" }))
```

Comment: adding **null** after controller name was helpful in my case.

Comment: This is effectively the same answer as @Jesse's answer with the added bonus that it covers the Ajax version, which is not what the OP asked for, but it is related to the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

This worked fine

```
@Html.ActionLink("Informationen", "About", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "nav-link" })
```

added `new { area = "" }`.

Answer (score 1):

As  Jonathon Watney pointed out in a comment, this also goes for

> Html.BeginForm()

methods. In my case, I was in a *Create.cshtml* targeting the post request of the corresponding controller + Create action and had

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Create")) {
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  ...
}
```

which was adding the querystring **"?Length=6"** to the form action when rendered. Hinted by roryf's approved answer and realizing the string length of "Create" is 6, I finally solved this by removing the explicit action specification:

```
using (Html.BeginForm()) {
      @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
      ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

With attribute names:

```
 @Html.ActionLink(linkText: "SomeText", actionName: "SomeAction", controllerName: "SomeControllerName", routeValues: new { parameterName = parameterValue}, htmlAttributes: null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps others had the same issue and need to supply a **class** value via *HTMLAttributes* parm.
Here's my solution:

```html
@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", new { controller = "Home", area = "" }, new { hidefocus = "hidefocus", @class = "nav-item nav-link" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Search for an answer to my question landed me here, basically it's the selection of correct overload of `@Html.ActionLink` 
[image]
which matters.

 I was selecting an overload which didn't exist, (*without* the *last* `null`), and ***`MVC`*** had no such overload, resulting in a false URL something like the OP mentioned.

A personal ***note:*** you can *`use`* anonymous types doesn't mean you can use any of the overloads- *which do* not exist? - ***make certain:*** *it* *has* to be defined!
*- Came here in times of MVC 5.2*