# Cyclic update of a container in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to create a cyclic updating container in ASP.NET Core MVC. That's how it look like

[image]

And here is the source code:

[AdminLTE](https://codinginfinite.com/creating-interactive-dashboards-asp-net-core-mvc/)

For the example in the image, if from database, here are 151 New Orders, when this part of panel is auto-updating, the value will be 151.

- One solution for me was to auto-update the whole page, but it's not ok.
- Second solution was to use Ajax to call the Index Controller, where I update the model's value from database each time controller is called. But this does not working, because to figure it out, the page must be refreshed. Not ok.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateModelData() {
        setInterval(updateModel, 3000);
        var i = 0;
        function updateModel() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/Index",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {

                    if (response.data.length == 0) {
                        // EMPTY
                    } else {
                        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response.data);
                        console.log(obj);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
    updateModelData();
</script>
```

So how can I make this informative section to get updated in an automatic cyclic mode?

```
<section class="content">
    <!-- Small boxes (Stat box) -->
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
        <!-- small box -->
        <div class="small-box bg-aqua">
        <div class="inner">
            <h3>@Model.doctors_count</h3>
            <p>Doctors</p>
        </div>
        <div class="icon">
            <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ./col -->
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
        <!-- small box -->
        <div class="small-box bg-green">
        <div class="inner">
            <h3>@Model.nurses_count<sup style="font-size: 20px"></sup></h3>
            <p>Nurses</p>
        </div>
        <div class="icon">
            <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ./col -->
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
        <!-- small box -->
        <div class="small-box bg-yellow">
        <div class="inner">
            <h3>@Model.patients_count</h3>
            <p>Patients</p>
        </div>
        <div class="icon">
            <i class="ion ion-person"></i>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ./col -->
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
        <!-- small box -->
        <div class="small-box bg-red">
        <div class="inner">
            <h3>65</h3>
            <p>This Month</p>
        </div>
        <div class="icon">
            <i class="ion ion-pie-graph"></i>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ./col -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use JavaScript function `setInterval()` and make an update per each desired time interval. See here for details and basic example: [JavaScript setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

On each time interval trigger an ajax call to a separate method in your controller that returns a partialview (so just the html code you want to update) and append it to your page (make sure you first empty the target container):

example 1: [JavaScript append html](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-append-html-code-to-a-div-using-javascript/)

example 2 (partialview/ajax update): [Update with partial view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15146212/can-you-just-update-a-partial-view-instead-of-full-page-post)

Answer (score 1):

> For the example in the image, if from database, here are 151 New Orders, when this part of panel is auto-updating, the value will be 151.

To achieve the requirement of updating particular content automatically based on the latest data from database, you can try:

1. If you'd like to make request to backend using Ajax etc to get data and update the DOM with retrieved data automatically, as @TheMixy mentioned, you can try to call your function repeatedly using `setInterval()` method.
2. Besides, you can try to integrate [ASP.NET Core SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-5.0) in your project, which could help implement real-time web functionality that enables server-side code to push content to clients instantly.

   You can call client methods to push data from server to all connected clients while you add/update orders from your backend code, then update the content on client side once it received the data.

Comment: If the scenario requires to send messages from outside a hub, you can check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-5.0