# MVC ActionLink renders wrong html?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, html-helper, actionlink

I written a custom `HtmlHelper` as the following:

```
public static MvcHtmlString MdActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string resourceId, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues = null, object htmlAttributes = null)
{
    if (routeValues == null && htmlAttributes != null)
        return htmlHelper.ActionLink(ResourcesHelper.GetMessageFromResource(resourceId), actionName, controllerName, htmlAttributes);

    return htmlHelper.ActionLink(ResourcesHelper.GetMessageFromResource(resourceId),
        actionName, controllerName,
        routeValues,
        htmlAttributes);
}
```

It's OK if `routeValues` and `htmlAttributes` both were null.
But if `htmlAttributes` has a value and `routeValues` was null, it render `a` tag as the follows:

```
<a comparer="System.Collections.Generic.GenericEqualityComparer`1[System.String]" count="1" keys="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+KeyCollection[System.String,System.Object]" values="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+ValueCollection[System.String,System.Object]" href="/Home/Login?Length=7">Exit</a>
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: I've just tested it, it doesn't change.

Comment: The same as usual, I guess, wrong overload http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357856/razor-actionlink-autogenerating-length-7-in-url

Comment: The only overload of `ActionLink` that accepts a `string` as the first 3 parameters also requires the 4th parameter as the route values and the 5th parameter as the html attributes, meaning if your `if` block evaluates to true, your rending the htmlAttributes as the route values. Just delete this helper - it does nothing at all that the inbuilt `ActionLink()` helpers don't already do.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString MdActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string resourceId, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues = null, object htmlAttributes = null)
{
    if (routeValues == null)
         routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary();

     if (htmlAttributes == null)
          htmlAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();

     htmlHelper.ActionLink(ResourcesHelper.GetMessageFromResource(resourceId),
        actionName, controllerName,
        routeValues,
        htmlAttributes);
}
```