# how to remove length from my url in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I m creating  an Mvc application . I have some issue .

I am getting url

> http://localhost:2355/Home/Contract?Length=4

I want my url as

> http://localhost:2355/Home/Contract

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Default",
  url: "{controller}/{action}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
);
```

what is problem in my route mapping

Comment: Could you post the `ActionLink` or `RouteLink` signature that you are using that is yielding this URL?

Comment: It means your using the wrong overload of `@Html.ActionLink()`. Show your code!

Comment: actually i m not using actionLink or routeLink ,used only  Maproute() method.

Comment: What? How are you generating that url is you not using `ActionLink` or `RouteLink`? `MapRoute` has nothing to do with it (it just defines a route, it does not generate a url)

Comment: Check this answer for comparison:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357856/razor-actionlink-autogenerating-length-7-in-url

Comment: Unless you show us how the URL is generated, we cannot really be of help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using @Html.ActionLink() you should try try these ones.

```
@Html.ActionLink("MyAction", "MyController", new { }, new { @Class="class-name"})
```

with Areas

```
@Html.ActionLink("MyAction", "MyController", new { }, new {@Area = "MyArea" @Class="class-name"})
```

Sendind data

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", new {  }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" }, new { @Area = "MyArea" }))
```

Sending data with no Area

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" }));
```

Besides that, you can check the [url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357856/razor-actionlink-autogenerating-length-7-in-url) which [@gardarvalur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1167735/gardarvalur) has posted.
I hope it helps you.