# @Html.ActionLink not working for css class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

Action link `@class="info"` not working for css

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click Here", "Details", "Product", new { id = item.ProductId, @class="info" },null)
```

Html page source

```
  <a href="/Product/Details/14?class=info">Click Here</a>
```

### Update:

on the other hand

if i set `@Html.ActionLink("link here", "Details", "Product", new { id = item.ProductId})` then generate this link `localhost:18715/Home/Details?Length=7` why? and it is not working

if  i set `@Html.ActionLink("link here", "Details", "Product", new { id = item.ProductId},null)`

it is working perfectly generate this link `http://localhost:18715/Product/Details/17`

what i am missing for each link

Comment: Remove `@class="info"`from the 4th parameter and add `new { @class="info" }` in lieu of the 5th parameter

Comment: @StephenMuecke if i set   @Html.ActionLink("link here", "Details", "Product", new { id = item.ProductId}) then generate this link http://localhost:18715/Home/Details?Length=7  why? would you   tell me please

Comment: You did not add `new { @class="info" }` in lieu of `null` for the last parameter :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke would you prompt answer ? with check my update Section

Comment: Maybe this can solve your problem: @Html.ActionLink("Click here", "Details", new { controller = "Product", id = item.ProductId }, new { @class = "info" })

Comment: @NazmulHasan, The answer by kkakkurt is correct. What is not working for you?

Comment: yes answer is correct ,if  i want to do without   @class = "info" then  @Html.ActionLink("link here", "Details", "Product", new { id = item.ProductId}) but why generate this link localhost:18715/Home/Details?Length=7

Comment: Because you still need the last `null` parameter, other wise `"Product"` is added as a route parameter and a `string` has only one property so it generates `length=7` because "Product" last a length of 7 (characters)

Comment: awesome!  Thank you so much .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write hmtl attributes like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click Here", "Details", "Product", new { id = item.ProductId }, new { @class = "info"})
```

Comment: would  you check my update section ? why it is not working and working

Comment: Maybe this can solve your problem: @Html.ActionLink("Click here", "Details", new { controller = "Product", id = item.ProductId }, new { @class = "info" })

Comment: yes answer is correct ,if i want to do without @class = "info" then @Html.ActionLink("link here", "Details", "Product", new { id = item.ProductId}) but why generate this link localhost:18715/Home/Details?Length=7

Comment: This post explains why is Html.ActionLink generating "length=7". Hope this post will be useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4360565/3401842

Answer (score 0):

```
  @Html.ActionLink("Back", "Index", " ", new { @class = "col-sm-3 btn btn-outline-secondary btnfs btn-sm" })
```

Here more than one CSS calls is attached to the for ActionLink. This is For
Asp.net MVC