# transfer value of parameter from one view to other?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i have 2 asp.net mvc views.

```
view1.aspx and view2.aspx.
```

of course they are `[HTTPGet] Actions` for each view as well Models `View1Model.cs and View2Model.cs`

in view1.aspc I have a hyperlink `<a href="\view2"></a>`, by clicking on it I'am landing on view2.aspx.
i want to pass some text message from view1 to view2 and display it on view2.aspx.

i want to do that with with POST method, how to do it?

Comment: Can you clarify your question, please.

Comment: @GlennFerrieLive: is now better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send a POST to any action by using an HTML form with the url as view2.aspx.

Any fields within that form (eg a hidden field) are then sent as POST data and can be accessed via a parameter in the view2 action or can be bound to View2Model.

You should use the [`Html.BeginForm()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410596.aspx) helper for this.

Answer (score 0):

I have to use just a proper HTML.ActionLink and thats it! 
Best answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824279/why-does-html-actionlink-render-length-4)