# @Html.ActionLink adds "?Length=4" in links

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I use

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Read More", "About", "Home", new {@class="button"})
```

in my Asp.NET MVC web site, but as result my link looks like this,

`http://localhost:43988/Home/About?Length=4`.

Why I get this part `?Length=4` in my links?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824279/why-does-html-actionlink-render-length-4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Read More", "About", "Home", null, new {@class="button"})
```

There is no overload as below see [msdn docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

```
@Html.ActionLink Method (HtmlHelper, String, String, String, Object)
```

Thus use

```
@Html.ActionLink Method (HtmlHelper, String, String, String, Object, Object)
```