# MVC my url is creating "?Length=4"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am creating an MVC4 application.
I have a small issue. 
My code is

```
<li id="tabHeader_2">@Html.ActionLink("Contract", "Contract", "Home", new { id = "lnk_contract" })</li>
```

I am getting url
`http://localhost:2355/Home/Contract?Length=4`

I want my url as
`http://localhost:2355/Home/Contract`

my ruoting is

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

If you have answer please help me ...

Comment: See this thread.. Its actually to do with the html action link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824279/why-does-html-actionlink-render-length-4

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You mixed up the parameters. You have to send anonymous object as htmlAttributes parameter.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Contract", "Contract", "Home", null ,new { id = "lnk_contract" })
```

Here's the MSDN page for this overload:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972(v=vs.108).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the parameter

```
, new {}
```

to `Html.ActionLink`.

The first object is for the query string, the second is for the HTML parameters.