# ActionLink and passing in url parameters

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

If I put `@Model.JamesID` above this line, it outputs `26`...

If I put it as below, the url has Length=4 added to it? Why is this?

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("James's list", "JamesList", "James", new { jamesID = @Model.JamesID })</li>
```

The controller is as so:

```
    public ViewResult JamesList(int jamesID)
    {
        James james = jamesRepository.GetByID(jamesID);
        return View(james);
    }
```

Comment: Dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824279/why-does-html-actionlink-render-length-4

Comment: Yes thankyou my friend... I found it hard to search for what I was looking for. :) thanks

Comment: NP.. Upvote would be nice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("James's list", "JamesList", "James", new { jamesID = @Model.JamesID }, null)</li>
```

You need to add null after your parameters, since it is expecting one more parameter as there is no overloaded method.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824279/why-does-html-actionlink-render-length-4) for explanation.

Comment: Yeahhhh buddy! nice one!... Daymmm I can't believe I missed that!