# MVC5 Actionlink: Pass data as query string

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Following is my Html.Actionlink

```
@Html.ActionLink("Change Team", "Edit", "UserPlayers", new { MatchId = ViewBag.MatchId, UserId = ViewBag.UserId })
```

When i run the application I get this

```
http://localhost:50013/UserPlayers/Edit?Length=11
```

as a link.

I dont know from where is the **"Length=11"** coming.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add a `null` as the last parameter:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Change Team", "Edit", "UserPlayers", new { MatchId = ViewBag.MatchId, UserId = ViewBag.UserId }, null)
```

Without this, you are using the wrong method overload for `Html.ActionLink()`

Comment: Why would that happen though? It is the wrong overload, the OP is adding HTML attributes to the link, but why would that cause it to append a Length parameter to the url?

Comment: @JMK  Because without the null, it is most likely hitting this overload of the action link - `public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, Object routeValues, Object htmlAttributes)` and is trying to convert the controller name into a route value (notice userplayers is 11 characters long).  Since it is not a dictionary or list, it gets all kinds of confused and outputs `?Length = 11`.  MSDN for reference - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

Comment: This answer explains the reason in more detail http://stackoverflow.com/a/824318/2082842