# Why does BeginForm("Foo") add a "Length" key to the query string?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, post, html.beginform

I am not new to MVC so I am a bit baffled at why I can't change the URL of my POST when I click the submit button.

I have this simple view called PandoraRemovalTool.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "PandoraRemovalTool";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("PandoraGetDocsList"))
{
    <h2>Pandora Removal Tool</h2>    
    @Html.Label("Member number:")
    @Html.TextBox("txtMemberNumber")
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
}
```

Because of it's simplicity I am not using a model, I only want to POST the txt value. However the URL is a bit odd. It's pointing to this path in the site:

```
<form action="/Administration/PandoraRemovalTool?Length=18" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">    
    <h2>Pandora Removal Tool</h2>
    <label for="Member_number:">Member number:</label>
    <input id="txtMemberNumber" name="txtMemberNumber" type="text" value=""/>        
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

I don't understand where it's getting length=18 from. I want to post to this method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PandoraGetDocsList(string txtMemberNumber)
{
    return RedirectToAction("PandoraRemovalTotal2", new {MemberNum = txtMemberNumber });
}

public ActionResult PandoraRemovalTotal2(string MemberNum)
{
    return View();
}
```

Some help please?

Comment: PandoraGetDocsList is the length 18 which you are getting

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace `@using (Html.BeginForm("PandoraGetDocsList"))` to `@using (Html.BeginForm())`

`PandoraGetDocsList` is the string of length 18 which you are getting in your post

If you want to redirect it to the action `PandoraGetDocsList` then do like this:

`@using (Html.BeginForm("PandoraGetDocsList", "Administration", new { txtMemberNumber = someString }))`

Explanation:
Html.BeginForm does not accept a parameter as string.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I did something very similar before I posted on SO and it didn't work so I must of missed something stupid.

Comment: Down Voters any comments/reasons?

Answer (score 4):

There is no overload that accepts just a `string` as parameter. It's using the [`BeginForm(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, Object routeValues)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470793.aspx) overload and because of that, [it attempts to serialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824279/why-does-html-actionlink-render-length-4) your `string` which is passed as an `object`.

> In the case of a `string` object, the only public property is `Length`, and since there will be no routes defined with a Length parameter it appends the property name and value as a query string parameter.

The overload you're looking for is [`BeginForm(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string actionName, string controllerName)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492590.aspx).

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PandoraGetDocsList", "controller name here"))
```