# in Razor view calling method of another controller and passing parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

In a view of ClimateChartController I do this code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Kies land", "ListCountries", "Continent" new {Selectedyear = @ViewBag.SchoolYear, continentId = @ViewBag.ContinentId})
```

So this should go to the method ListCountries of ContinentController, along with the given parameters.

Now this doesn't work, if I do it without the parameters it goes to the method but well, I need the parameters...

For now I resolved this by using the following method in ClimateChartController:

```
public ActionResult ListCountries(int selectedyear, int continentid)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ListCountries", "Continent",
                new { selectedYear = selectedyear, continentId = continentid });
        }
```

This works as intended, but causes cluttering of code and isn't neat.

So how can I call a method of another controller and pass some parameters with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Kies land", "ListCountries", "Continent" , null, new {Selectedyear = @ViewBag.SchoolYear, continentId = @ViewBag.ContinentId})
```

OR:

```
Html.ActionLink("Kies land", "ListCountries", "Continent", new {Selectedyear = @ViewBag.SchoolYear, continentId = @ViewBag.ContinentId}, null)
```

There are possible solutions here:

[Why does Html.ActionLink render "?Length=4"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824279/why-does-html-actionlink-render-length-4)

Comment: I alrey tried the first solution u gave, which didn't work, the second one does, thanks!