# MVC dynamic pages from list

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller

I have a page which represents data from `ICollection<>` model, it generates `@Html.BeginForm()` for each item in `ICollection<>` and shows data with `@Html.Labels`, and I want to create a link from each form to item details, so it will be like, when I press form with item with id=4, it sends `Model.ElementAt(4)` as a model to new page, and display it. How can I do that?

EDIT: I guess I need to add something like @Html.ActionLink("DetailsPage","Shops",shop)

```
@using WebShops
@model ICollection<WebShops.Shop>
@foreach (Shop shop in Model)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.Label(shop.name)
        @Html.Display(shop.name)
        <br />
        @Html.Label(shop.image)
        @Html.Display(shop.image)
        <hr />
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display a specific item there is no need for `Html.BeginForm` because it makes a `POST` request and you need to make a `GET` request.

You need to create a new Action that will make use of `GET` request.

```
public ActionResult Shop(string id)
{
     var shop =  //get shop by id from database
     return View(shop)
}
```

You call the new action like below.

```
@using WebShops
@model ICollection<WebShops.Shop>
@foreach (Shop shop in Model)
{
        @Html.Label(shop.name)
        @Html.Display(shop.name)
        <br />
        @Html.Label(shop.image)
        @Html.Display(shop.image)
        <hr />
        @Html.ActionLink("Display", "Shop","ControllerName", new {id = shop.id})
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using the `object routeValues` from [this overload of `Html.ActionLink`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492936(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
@Html.ActionLink("DetailsPage","Shops", new { id = shop.ID })
```

This doesn't "send the model to the new page", it makes a link to  `Shops/DetailsPage/4`, causing GET request when clicked.

So in the `DetailsPage` action method you'll have to look up the shop on ID again in order to display it.

Comment: @Andrey for your now removed comment, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824279/why-does-html-actionlink-render-length-4.