# ASP.NET MVC partial view parameter from jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I am working on Location Detector Module of the Project

Detecting latitude and longitude using jQuery, there is a button that submit the ajax form to the action and that action return partial view.

How can I send auto parameter to the action and get the partial view

I used

```
document.getElementById("fmDis").submit();
```

but it creates `?length=4` in url

I am using ajax form with hidden values

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("DistanceFound", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "partial" }, new { id = "fmDis" }))
{
    <input type="hidden" id="lat" name="lat" />
    <input type="hidden" id="lon" name="lon" />
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

Comment: Are you wanting to add the latitude and longitude as route values rather that using hidden inputs

Comment: no i just want that when ever application open it submit auto and partial view shows

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20180627/1138165 this post might be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You using the wrong overload of `Ajax.BeginForm` where the second parameter (`"Home"`) is being added as a route value. It needs to be [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.AjaxExtensions.BeginForm%28System.Web.Mvc.AjaxHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary,System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.AjaxOptions,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary%7BSystem.String,System.Object%7D%29)

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("DistanceFound", "Home", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "partial" }, new { id = "fmDis" }))
```

Note your hidden inputs do not have a `value` attribute, so I assume you are setting their values in a script before you submit the form

Comment: problem is when i open the page and it will show button click on button then form is submit   but i need it auto with out button

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. - My answer was addressing why you are getting `?length=4`

Comment: now as you said i used null value now my partial view is open in new windows

Comment: Thats because you have not included `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` (or have included the scripts in the wrong order or have duplicated them)

Comment: <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
    @RenderSection("script", required: false)

here is order of the jqueery

Comment: my script comes in render section  scripts

Comment: That looks fine (assuming you have no duplicates), but from your comments are you trying to submit the form without actually clicking on the button? - in which case you can give the button a `id="submit"` and use `$('#submit').trigger('click');`

Comment: You could put the button inside a `<div>` with `style="display: none;"`. But we are getting of track (the question was about the url) and I have no idea what you scripts are so you should ask a new question explaining the issue and including the relevant code.

Comment: But really, there is no need at all for `AjaxBeginForm()` - you can just use ajax to post the form and update the DOM with the partial view the method returns in the success call back (using `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` is just unnecessary extra overhead)