# Passing parameters into htm.actionlink giving strange result

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, view

I have a with passing parameters into htm.action link

My code :

Controller :

```
    public ActionResult NewsInfo(string id)
    {
        ViewBag.Messege = "News Detail";

        return View(new NewsInfoModel(id));
    }
```

Model :

```
public class NewsInfoModel
{
    public NewsDto News { get; private set; }
    public List<ComentDto> comentList { get; private set; }

    public NewsInfoModel(string id)
    {
        comentList = new Coment().MakeComentListForNews(id);
        News = new NewsDao().GetNewsByID(id);
    }
}
```

And code to link in view :

```
@Html.ActionLink("more >>", "NewsInfo", "Home", new { id = news.Id });
```

The problem is when I start my web page link have format like :

```
http://localhost:52748/Home/NewsInfo?Length=4
```

Why `Lenght = 4` ? To get it work for now i made code like this :

```
<a href="/home/NewsInfo?id=@news.Id"> more >>  </a>
```

And it work proper but I want to use `ActionLink` so how to pass parameters there proper ? What is difference between those two methods.
And last question this link display `more >>;` (with semicolon at end where it get from ?)

If answer is oblivious don't be angry i'm starting mvc thing

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`@Html.ActionLink("more >>", "NewsInfo", "Home", new { id = news.Id }, null);`

Adding null as the last parameter. I think I've seen this before, and adding null did the trick.

I'm not sure where the `length` comes from, but this is weird side-effect of having so many overloads for `Html.ActionLink`.

EDIT:

Ah, just found this:

[Why does Html.ActionLink render “?Length=4”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824279/why-does-html-actionlink-render-length-4)

Comment: When I add it at end it start works thanks very much. This `lenght` is so strange but it dispirited now. :)