# ASP.NET MVC routing whit @Html.ActionLink doesn't work correctly when I add parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I don't understand why if I add parameters on my @Html.ActionLink() the root doesn't go in the correct way.

In fact if I use this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Torna alla lista", "Index", "VwOpenOrders")
```

The program rooting on "/VwOpenOrders" that is what I aspect.

If I add parameter like this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Torna alla lista", "Index", "VwOpenOrders", new { SearchLV = TempData["SearchLV"]})
```

It go on root "/VwFases?Length=12", where "VwFase" is the controller of the page where I launch the action link.

Please someone can help me? 
what am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: You using the wrong overload - it need to be `@Html.ActionLink("Torna alla lista", "Index", "VwOpenOrders", new { SearchLV = TempData["SearchLV"]}, null)` - note the 5th parameter

Comment: This is more proper as dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824279/why-does-html-actionlink-render-length-4.

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The overload of ActionLink you should try to use is the following:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    object routeValues,
    object htmlAttributes
)
```

That being said you should change you code as below:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Torna alla lista"
                , "Index"
                , "VwOpenOrders"
                , new { SearchLV = TempData["SearchLV"]}
                , null)
```

For a detailed listing of ActionLink overloads please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Object%29).

Comment: Thank youj so much!

Comment: @Dona You are very welcome

Answer (score 0):

You should use the below instead

```
@Html.ActionLink("Torna alla lista", "Index", "VwOpenOrders", new { SearchLV = TempData["SearchLV"]},null)
```

by adding additional parameter of "null" to get the right overload for the method

Comment: Thank youj so much!

Answer (score 0):

You're actually using this [`ActionLink` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Object,System.Object%29):

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    object routeValues,
    object htmlAttributes
)
```

The third parameter is `routeValues`, not `controllerName`, so that `Length=12` is length of string `VwOpenOrders` supplied to it. What you should do is using `controller` parameter:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Torna alla lista", "Index", new { controller = "VwOpenOrders" }, new { SearchLV = TempData["SearchLV"]})
```

Or using [overload which accepts 5 arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Object,System.Object%29):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Torna alla lista", "Index", "VwOpenOrders", new { SearchLV = TempData["SearchLV"]}, null)
```

Comment: Thank youj so much!